# What is the shebang for Anaconda Python?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, shebang

There are 2 python versions (Python Vanilla & Anaconda) both 3.7.3-64 bit.

`#!python3.7.3-64` - for Python vanilla

What is the shebang for Anaconda?

`#!C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe` is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

> In this case you need to write something like this:
>
> ```
> #!path/to/anaconda/bin/python
> ```

[What shebang for Anaconda Python on my directory of Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/731802/what-shebang-for-anaconda-python-on-my-directory-of-server)

Maybe you can use two virtual environment, one with python, one with conda?

- [venv — Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/venv.html)
- [Create virtual environments for python with conda](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)